# File download in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I set it so that when a link is clicked in a view, it prompts the user to download a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just return a FileResultType.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make a link to a downloadable file.

If you want us to give more details, you'll need to give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try Server.TransmitFile() method.  That's what I do it in ASP.NET WebForms and I would imagine it's the same in MVC.