# How to display a 'Save as' dialog box for an Excel file generated through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Rather than saving a file silently to a default path, I want to give the user the option to save the excel file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's not really ASP.NET MVC question, but anyway:

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value) as Excel.Workbook;

...

object filename = excel.GetSaveAsFilename("DefaultName.xls", 
    "Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (*.xls), *.xls", Missing.Value, 
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

if (!(filename is bool))
{
    workbook.SaveAs(filename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        excel.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom ActionResult class which will display the Save As dialog.
Phil Haack has [an excellent tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx) about that.

Comment: Im generating a new file...it doesnt already exist...so providng a path is not an option
Also im using Interop.Excel...

Comment: Can't you save the created file first and delete it afterwards? What do you mean with 'im using Interop.Excel' ?

Comment: That's ok, but I think it doesn't matter for the question :-) But can't you save the created file first, let the user download it and delete the file after the download? (after a period of time?)

Comment: that means the file would be saved twice wouldnt it???..:D
i want to save it jst once...that too the user should decide the path!!

Comment: i mean without saving it on the server cant the user download it to his local system wth the dialog box???

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937701/file-download-in-mvc-application) deals with downloading a file in asp.net MVC (by using the FileResultType)...your simply choosing to send an excel file which should still apply.

Comment: im not using the FileResult type....im using the The Excel Object library....any solution??/